# how to represent a JSON as class in c#

Tags: asp.net, json, xml, c#-4.0

I am triggering an API that is returning as

```
 {"result":
    [{"number":"VAL0010101",
    "short_description":"EFGH ",
    "sys_created_on":"2017-02-02 12:36:24",
    "state":"2",
    "subcategory":"XYZ",
    "assignment_group.name":"ABCD"}]
    }
```

I want to get it in classes. I am able to achieve this partially by using `Paste Special in visual studio` 
and it is as below

```
public class getdetails
    {
        public Result[] result { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string number { get; set; }
        public string short_description { get; set; }
        public string sys_created_on { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string subcategory { get; set; }
        public string assignment_groupname { get; set; }

    }
```

but I am not able the get value in `assignment_groupname` because in json it is `assignment_group.name`. How to solve this

**EDITED UPDATED QUESTION**
 I am deserializing it using this
`getdetails Details = new getdetails();
Details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<getdetails>(result.Result);`

Comment: how are you desalinizing it. would you please share that part too ?

Comment: r u using restsharp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the name for the property with [JsonPropertyAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm)

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "assignment_group.name")]
public string assignment_groupname { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create another class `assignment_group` which will hold the name property:

```
 public assignment_group {
   public string name { get; set; }
 }
```

And then::

```
public class getdetails
    {
        public Result[] result { get; set; }
    }

public class Result
{
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string short_description { get; set; }
    public string sys_created_on { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string subcategory { get; set; }
    public assignment_group assignment_group { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: this is not helping I have already tried. Shall I Show the XML result?

Comment: @saikatmukherjee What's the error message? Please, share the xml result

Comment: there is no error message. Anyways the problem got resolved. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using RestSharp, try using

```
[JsonProperty("assignment_group.name")]
public string assignment_groupname { get; set; }
```